# angular-rails-templates Failed to load template

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, angularjs-templates

I'm trying to get Angular to load a template:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ['templates'])
```

and my html:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-include="'blah.html'"></div>
</div>
```

But all I get is a `404` `Failed to load resource` because, Rails tells me, `No route matches [GET] "/blah.html"`. I understand that this is because of the asset pipeline in Rails. `blah.html` is in `/app/assets/javascripts/templates/blah.html` and I am using the `angular-rails-templates` gem to try to solve the problem. So my `application.js` has:

```
//= require angular-rails-templates
//= require_tree ./templates
```

But I'm not having any luck.

The html generated suggests that `angular-rails-templates` is loading (it has a script `/assets/angular-rails-templates....js`) but rails is failing to find `blah.html`

> **Versions:** 
>   rails 4.2.1
>   angular-rails-templates 0.1.4
>   angularjs 1.3.15

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This turned out to be a sprockets incompatibility (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29757003/123415) and [here](http://www.ademartutor.com/angular-rails-templates-gem-error-with-sprockets-3-0-o/))

The short version is:

1. Add `gem 'sprockets', '2.12.3'` to your Gemfile
2. Run `bundle update sprockets`

**[Update]**
I'm no expert on this stuff but it does seem that a number of people smarter than I are suggesting using `/public/templates`. You may want to bear this in mind.

Comment: @jcuenod my mistake. I mixed up "sprockets" and "sprockets-rails"

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue - In my haste, I neglected to fully read the directions, and missed [step 3](https://github.com/pitr/angular-rails-templates#3-add-a-dependency-in-your-angular-application-module).

Adding a Dependency in the Angular Application Module solved it for me, and the templates are served through the asset pipeline...

```
//= require angular-rails-templates
//= require_tree .

angular.module('d-angular', ['templates'])
```

Answer (score 1):

I put my angular template files under `public/templates` which is accessible via `<site root>/templates` without any additional configuration.

Comment: That's only going to work if rails is not preprocessing your assets. Like I say, I'm a noob, but it seems that the "rails way" is not to assume the contents of your public folder and let rails generate it.

Comment: Unless you need pre-processing done on your templates, using `public/` [is fine](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#asset-organization).

"Assets can still be placed in the public hierarchy. Any assets under public will be served as static files by the application or web server when config.serve_static_files is set to true. You should use app/assets for files that must undergo some pre-processing before they are served."

Comment: That's interesting. Thanks. I hadn't realised that you could really use the `public/` folder. The problem though is that as soon as I want to chuck some `erb` or whatever into one of those files, I'm stymied.

Answer (score 1):

After struggling for an hour to get this, I realized that I had a JavaScript file sharing the same name.

For example, these files will cause conflict:

```
component.js
component.html.haml
```

So I made sure to rename the JavaScript file to something like:

```
component-directive.js
component.html.haml
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling on the same problem today, and I think I have found a solution for this problem.

try

```
<div ng-include="'assets/blah.html'"></div>
```

OR

```
<div ng-include="'assets/templates/blah.html'"></div>
```

instead of

```
<div ng-include="'blah.html'"></div>
```

This solved the problem for me.

Comment: This didn't solve it for me. One thing it made me notice though was that the URL I visited was defining where angular was looking for the template - the url was `host.com/controller/assets/blah.html` (and changed as I tried with and without templates and with the root path)