# Angular Templates on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, angular-template

I'm using the `angular-rails-templates` gem. I have a folder in my `/app/assets/javascripts` called `templates` and I have included it in `application.js`:

```
//= require_tree ./templates
```

Inside of templates there is a `test.html` file with `<h1>hello world</h1>`.

For some reason, `test.html` is not being found though, when I log out `$templateCache.info()` (using `app.run`) in the console I have:

> Object {id: "templates", size: 0}

Comment: I'd really recommend you to keep templates out of the asset pipeline. You could serve them with a standard controller

Comment: @apneadiving thanks but why? Also, if it's *really* recommended, what's the point of `angular-rails-templates`? (you don't need to serve them with a controller, can't you just put them in `/public`)

Comment: ok, so my point is you should not clutter your asset pipeline. Dont know this gem but if it puts stuff in `/public`, its fine

Comment: The gem seems to be what people recommend to use when you're trying to use angular templates with rails (which is all I'm trying to figure out)

Comment: from what I can see, it puts your templates in your assets, and I wouldnt recommend this :) but you know tastes and colors...

Comment: just curious - why would you not recommend it?

Comment: because you add load to your js files where templates are just meant to be retrieved through usual queries

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75753/discussion-between-jcuenod-and-apneadiving).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be a sprockets incompatibility (see [here](http://www.ademartutor.com/angular-rails-templates-gem-error-with-sprockets-3-0-o/))

The short version is:

1. Add `gem 'sprockets', '2.12.3'` to your Gemfile
2. Run `bundle update sprockets`